# Does using composite keys violate 2NF?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

From all of the database related reference books that I have come across, there is a universal rule that state a database table should be at least 3NF.

From what I understand, a table is considered 2NF if it satisfies 1NF and it has single column primary key. Correct me if I am wrong.

So I couldn't understand why there is so much argument of having composite key especially for entities that relate M:N tables; eg:

A `Product_Customer` table, with the columns:

- `CustomerProductID`
- `CustomerID`
- `ProductID`

Some say that primary key (`CustomerProductID`) is not needed and it should use composite key (`CustomerID, ProductID`) instead.

But doesn't that violate the universal rule of a table should have at least 3NF since using a composite key will not even satisfy 2NF?

Correct me if I am wrong, especially the part where I understand that if a table has composite keys, it will not be in 2NF.

Answer (score 11):

Your definition of 2NF is not quite correct.

2NF is when a relation is in 1NF and it has **no partial dependencies**, meaning there are no predicates (columns) that depend on only part of a multi-part key.

What that means is that a table where all the (one or more) keys are single column ones cannot *violate* 2NF by definition.  However, it's also possible to have a table with a multi column (composite) key which *also* doesn't violate 2NF.  It's not about how many columns are in your key, its about whether there are non-key columns which depend on only **part** of any candidate key.

Since it's possible for a table to have a multi column key be in 2NF, it's also possible for a table with a multi column key to be in 3NF.  You just have to make sure there are no transitive dependencies as well.

Comment: A table with a single column key can violate 2NF if it has multiple keys.

Comment: @David right, corrected.t

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I wouldn't say that multiple single column candidate keys would allow for a partial dependency (and therefore a violation of 2NF).  Every non-key column would have to be functionally dependent on each candidate key (otherwise it wouldn't be a candidate key).  To violate 2NF you need a composite candidate key.

Comment: Yes.  I just meant that the addition of a single column key wouldn’t “fix” a non 2NF table.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, quite so. Too many people are too quick to throw an IDENTITY / AutoNumber into a table thinking they no longer have to worry about other candidate keys and insert/update anomalies.

Comment: All-CKs-simple violates 2NF when {} functionally determines a non-prime attribute, which is when the attribute has to have the same value in every row. Also 2NF is no partial dependencies where a CK determines a non-prime attribute.